# How does gaussian quadrature work for this example?

Tags: numerical-methods, quadrature

I'm trying to determine the weights for the following integral using gaussian quadrature:

$\int_{0}^{1} x^2 f(x) \approx w_0 f(0) + w_1 f(a)$

I understand that you write polynomials from $\ x^n$ where n = 0, 1, 2...

I am confused when it comes to evaluating the first couple of lines of this:

if we take $x^0$ then would this yield $\int_{0}^{1} x^2 x^0 = \frac{1}{3} \approx w_0 *0  + w_1$ which implies $\ \frac{1}{3} = w_1$ or is this not how it works? I am quite unsure about this example in specific, if the latter equation is correct, then what would the weight of $w_0$ evaluate to (since it always going to be 0 in the equation)? Also, would the order of precision for this equation be 2?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ It should be $\frac{1}{3}=w_0+w_1$, since $f(x)=x^0=1$ is constant. Next, you impose exactness on $f(x)=x,$ which gives a second equation $$\int\limits_0^1 x\cdot x^2\, dx=w_0\cdot 0+w_1\cdot a,$$ or $$\frac{1}{4}=aw_1.$$ Now, you have a $2\times 2$ system of linear equations that you can solve to find $w_0,$ $w_1.$

$2)$ A Gaussian quadrature rule with $n$ nodes will have a degree of precision of $2n-1.$ If $n=2,$ then the degree of precision would be $3$. However, you need to check if these nodes came from performing Gaussian quadrature, as was claimed. Not every set of nodes is going to give you a Gaussian quadrature rule. It seems like what you’re referring to is the process of undetermined coefficients to find the weights; Gaussian quadrature is more substantial and involves choosing the nodes appropriately. If you want to check exactness in the given rule, with $a$ provided to you, do the process outlined in step 1) to find the weights, then test on $x^2,\cdots$. If you want to choose the weights and one of the nodes, see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The formula can't be exact for polynomials of order $3$ because
$$\int_0^1x^2\cdot x(x-a)^2dx>0$$
Because the integrand is positive except at isolated points whereas the integration formula says its value is zero. If it is to be exact for polynomials of order $2$ then we must have
$$\int_0^1x^2\cdot x(x-a)\cdot x^ndx=0$$
For $0\le n<1$. This is kind of trivial in this case but in general with $n$ interior points and the one endpoint $x=0$ you need to construct a polynomial orthogonal to all polynomials of lesser degree with respect to the weight function $x^2\cdot x$ over the interval $(0,1)$. The only polynomial of lesser degree in this case is $f(x)=1$ so we want
$$\int_0^1x^3(x-a)dx=\frac15-\frac14a=0$$
So $a=4/5$. Now we can evaluate
$$\int_0^1x^2(x-a)dx=\frac14-\frac13a=\frac14-\frac13\cdot\frac45=-\frac1{60}=w_0(0-a)=-\frac45w_0$$
So $w_0=\frac1{48}$. And again
$$\int_0^1x^2\cdot xdx=\frac14=w_1(a)=\frac45w_1$$
So $w_1=\frac5{16}$. Check:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1x^2\cdot1dx&=\frac13=\frac1{48}(1)+\frac5{16}(1)\\
\int_0^1x^2\cdot xdx&=\frac14=\frac1{48}(0)+\frac5{16}\left(\frac45\right)\\
\int_0^1x^2\cdot x^2dx&=\frac15=\frac1{48}(0)+\frac5{16}\left(\frac45\right)^2\end{align}$$
This is called left-Radau-Jacobi integration.

Comment: I just saw the term “Gaussian quadrature” and assumed the nodes were chosen appropriately without even looking at them. Thanks for pointing that out, had to edit.

Comment: Since the questioner specified "Gaussian" but specified the left endpoint, I assumed he meant that the interior points were free to float, which would be left-Radau. For example with $x_0=0$ fixed and $3$ floating interior points $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ we get $x_j=\frac23-\frac13\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}\left(\frac27\right)+\frac{2\pi j}3\right)$ and $w_0=\frac1{1200}$, $w_j=\frac7{400}\left(-36w_j^2+56w_j-13\right)$.

Comment: @user5713482 I agree with you. When I first read it, I saw it asked about Gaussian quadrature and then asked about finding the weights. I think that this is, at least, what should've been asked, though.

Answer (score 0):

With Gaussian quadrature  we have $$\int_{-1}^1g(x)dx \approx g(-1/{\sqrt 3})+ g(1/{\sqrt 3})$$

Thus $$\int_0^1x^2f(x)dx=1/2 \int_{-1}^1 (\frac {t+1}{2})f(\frac {t+1}{2})dt\approx $$

$$(1/2)\int_{-1}^1 g(t)dt \approx (1/2) [g(-1/{\sqrt 3})+ g(1/{\sqrt 3})]$$

Comment: I’m just wondering if my approach above is correct? Also this is suggesting that the weights of w and alpha = what exactly? There is an f(0)